# Как сделать что бы при нажатии кнопки менялся фон ? (OnTouch)

Tags: java, android

Есть набор кнопок, все нажатия обрабатываются с помощью `OnClick`, и с ними проблем никаких нет. Две кнопки обрабатываются с помощью `OnTouch`, и при нажатии на них фон кнопки не меняется.

1. Как мне сделать что бы фон менялся, если убрать `onTouch` не
   получается?
2. Можно ли сделать обработку действий в `OnClick`

Вот код

```
 button_left.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int RightEngine = 0 , LeftEngine = 0;
                currentLog++;
                if(currentLog>100) currentLog= 100;
                RightEngine = (int) (21.7*Math.log((double)currentLog));
                LeftEngine = (int) -(21.7*Math.log((double)currentLog));
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
                        flagButton = true;
                        label = false;
                        leftEngineVal = LeftEngine;
                        rightEngineVal = RightEngine;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        label = false;
                        flagButton = true;
                        leftEngineVal = LeftEngine;
                        rightEngineVal = RightEngine;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:// отпускание
                        flagButton = false;
                        label = true;
                        currentLog=0;
                        leftEngineVal=rightEngineVal=0;
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Такая же есть `buttonRight`

selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/left_pressed"
        />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/left"
        />
</selector>
```

P.S.Я новичок в Android не судите строго.Замена картинки производится с помощью selector, из действий мне нужны `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`,`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` и `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`

Comment: Замените onTouch на onClick

Comment: @Werder не могу, мне нужны средства onTouch

Comment: @Werder как считывать MotionEvent в OnClick

Comment: да, в onClick этого не сделать, поэтому покажите код и объясните лучше что вы имеете ввиду под "что бы фон менялся, если убрать onTouch не получается"

Comment: код в студию! Код селектора, и код onTouch()

Comment: @metalurgus код

Comment: @Werder код есть

Comment: А програмно пробовали менять бэкграунд?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Пробовал через setBackground, не получалось потом где то вычитал что во время выполнения нельзя менять типа ссылки на ресурс что ли, или что-то в этом роде, не вникал потому что нашел сразу инфу про selector-ы

Comment: @metalurgus все верно,спасибо все работает

Comment: @metalurgus  а почему так, как это влияло на background ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можете попробовать возвращать из `onTouch` `false` вместо `true`

Comment: Все таки почему это влияет на background?

Comment: @AmirShabanov, `onTouch` возвращает true, если он обработал тач. А, видимо, если он обработал его, то никаких дальнейших действий (включая обработку состояния для фона `View`) выполняться не будет. Вообще правильнее будет наверно написать `return super.onTouch()`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я очень благодарен вам!